# Use cases of the GCC "artificial" function attribute

Tags: c, gcc, attributes

I just read about the GCC function attribute `artificial` but did not quite get the description. Can you give me some examples where it is useful?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The other answer isn't wrong, but perhaps I can explain it a bit better.

Imagine this function in `foo.c`, with line numbers:

```
10: static inline int foo(struct q *x)
11: {
12:     return bar(x + 1);
13: }
```

This is called twice from another function:

```
20: void baz(void)
21: {
22:     x = foo(qa);
23:     x = foo(qb);
24: }
```

Unfortunately, `bar()` crashes. Here's the backtrace:
   `#0  0x00000000004b1a2a in bar (x=0x8) at foo.c:5 
    #1  0x0000000000416ee0 in baz () at foo.c:12
    #2  0x0000000000413fab in main () at foo.c:30`

Since `foo` is inlined, it's not part of the backtrace, but wait, `foo.c:12` is in `foo`, and below it is just the line in `main`. There's nothing to tell us what line in `baz` caused the crash.

If we mark foo as artificial, we'd instead get this backtrace:
   `#0  0x00000000004b1a2a in bar (x=0x8) at foo.c:5
    #1  0x0000000000416ee0 in baz () at foo.c:22
    #2  0x0000000000413fab in main () at foo.c:30`

It no longer points to `foo`. Instead it shows us where `foo` was called from `foo.c:22`. Suddendly it's easy to tell that `qa` is the problematic variable.

Answer (score 4):

### artificial

From the gcc docs,

> This attribute is useful for small inline wrappers that if possible should appear during debugging as a unit. Depending on the debug info format it either means marking the function as artificial or using the caller location for all instructions within the inlined body.

In the [Inline is as fast as a Macro](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html), there is a special note at the end on `extern inline` functions.  The idea is that if you have a header with the `extern inline`, you can use the *artificial* attribute and the debug information will use the location where the `inline` is used.  Ie, where the `extern inline` is called and *inlined*.

As in the description, **artificial** is only ever used with inlining and it controls the way a debugger will treat this code.  It doesn't have an effect on generated code or anything else.

Comment: I fear I still don't get it. So is this about not using the file/line information from the "real" implementation (i.e. where it is not extern) but the location of the place where it is inlined? The "caller location for all instructions" irritates me.

Comment: No one can answer your question without knowing what debug format you use.  My main point is, it will do nothing to generated code.  It should only matter if you are stepping in a debugger; In some cases, you might wish to set a break-point for only the in-lined location.  In others, you want every call to hit a break point.  What gdb can do will depend on the kind of information available.

Answer (score 1):

According to Ian Lance Taylor, one of the GCC devs, at [`__gnu_inline__` and `__artificial__`](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2010-07/msg00295.html):

> I admit the docs for the artificial attribute are not very good.  On a
>   function, it basically means that if the function is inlined, the
>   debugger will not step through the inlined instructions.

---

> Can you give me some examples where it is useful?

I can provide at least one additional one: stepping code with inline assembly one-liners from C. Often times, you want the next C statement, not the next assembly statement.