# Can I tell my compiler to "inline" a function also w.r.t. debug/source-line info?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, clang, debug-information

In my code (either C or C++; let's say it's C++) I have a one-liner inline function `foo()` which gets called from many places in the code. I'm using a profiling tool which gathers statistics by line in the object code, which it translates into statistics by using the source-code-line information (which we get with `-g` in clang or GCC). Thus the profiler can't distinguish between calls to `foo()` from different places.

I would like the stats to be counted separately for the different places `foo()` get called. For this to happen, I need the compiler to "fully" inline `foo()` - including forgetting about it when it comes to the source location information.

Now, I know I can achieve this by using a macro - that way, there is no function, and the code is just pasted where I use it. But that wont work for operators, for example; and it may be a problem with templates. So, can I tell the compiler to do what I described?

Notes:

- Compiler-specific answers are relevant; I'm mainly interested in GCC and clang.
- I'm not compiling a debug build, i.e. optimizations are turned on.

Comment: I'm guessing (maybe you could add some clarity) that, for debug builds, any `inline` keyword is ignored because inlining is considered an optimization.

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/240228/can39t-debug-inline-functions-vc-2019.html) is a blog about debug/inline for MSVC. May it helps?

Comment: I have not tried it, but maybe [__attribute__((artificial))](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) would [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21936099/4074081) in this case as well.

Comment: The debug info has all the information if and where a function was inlined.

Comment: Can't you look at the places where `foo()` is called? The output of your profiling tool should give you counts there. And a simple "grep" will reveal them.

Comment: @thebusybee: It's not giving me the counts at the call sites. The counts are by object code line, and each of those is associated with a single line in the source.

Comment: @AdrianMole: I'm not profiling a debug build.

Comment: I might be misled by a lack of experience with gprof, I used gcov mainly. Its coverage counts are by source lines. -- So you want a profiler to count inlined machine code instructions generated by an inlined function? On heavily optimized code this seems impossible.

Comment: @thebusybee: My profiling tool (not gcov, not gprof) counts by object code lines, and using that, counts by source code lines. I just want to change the mapping between the two.

Comment: So you have a connection between object code and source. Can't you use it?

Comment: @thebusybee: I can, but if my count has "123456 mcguffins" for the the instruction at 0x1f00, and that instruction is mapped to the single line of `foo()`, that doesn't help me know which of these million mcguffins happen at which call to `foo()`.

Comment: Huh? The instruction at 0x1f00 was executed 123456 times, so this specific call of `foo()` happened 123456 times. -- If this is not what you want, please elaborate your question. Especially, why you think that you cannot differentiate different call places that are at separate instruction locations. A [mre] would be most helpful.

Comment: @thebusybee: I elaborated my question fine. I want that count broken down by where the function was called for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248894/discussion-between-the-busybee-and-einpoklum).